# how i can execute scripts of multiple classes in xml file using TestNG frame work

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium

I have automated an android application and written test scripts in three different classes. Day by day, I need more classes for writing the test scripts as I am facing a problem. When executing the test scripts in a class it is working fine. When i want to execute these test scripts in the XML file there are execute only 3 test cases.

I have implemented a configuration class where i launch my application and this class is extended in other classes.

```
package com.macrosoft.CherryPick;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class Configuration {
    public AndroidDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void CherryPikLaunch() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        // Create object of DesiredCapabilities class and specify android platform
        // Create object of DesiredCapabilities class

        // File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        // File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/Amazon/");
        // File app = new File(appDir, "selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk");
        // DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().android();
        // capabilities.setCapability("no",true);
        // capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 100000);
        // capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);

        // Optional

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

        // Specify the device name (any name)

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy S4");

        // Platform version

        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1.0");

        // platform name

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        // specify the application package that we copied from appium
        // capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development");

        // specify the application activity that we copied from appium

        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.activity.SplashActivity");
        // capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",".DispatchActivity");
        // appWaitActivity = .DispatchActivity;

        // Start android driver I used 4727 port by default it will be 4723

        // driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
        // capabilities);
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        // Specify the implicit wait of 5 second

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // close the application
        // driver.quit();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.print("Successfully launched the Application\n");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.print("Exception is displayed" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void close_browser() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Toolsrefferalcode class is working fine seprately but not executed in xml file

```
package com.macrosoft.CherryPick;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotEquals;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertFalse;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class ToolsReferralCode extends Configuration {
    public String BrandNameOnBrandDetailScreen;

    // public AndroidDriver driver;
    public ToolsReferralCode() {
    }
    // public AndroidDriver driver;

    /*
     * ToolsReferralCode() { }
     */

    /*******************************
     * Your Referral code Scripts
     ************************************/
    @Test(priority = 1) // verify that Tools screen Opens successfully
    public void OpenToolsScreen() {
        WebElement ToolsButtonElement = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/footer_nav_settings_btn"));// Find Tools
                                                                                                            // Button ID
        ToolsButtonElement.click();// click on tools button
        WebElement ScreenTitleFindElement = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/tv_screen_title"));// Find the Id of
                                                                                                    // Screen tile
        String ScreentitleActualText = ScreenTitleFindElement.getText();// Get the Text of Title
        Assert.assertEquals("Tools & Settings", ScreentitleActualText);// compare Actual Result with Expected Result
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            // System.out.print("Successfully Opened the Tools Screen\n");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.print("Exception is displayed" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test(priority = 2) // Verify that on tools screen title is exist or not
    public void OnToolsScreenTitlePresist() {
        WebElement ScreenTitleFindElement = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/tv_screen_title"));// Find the Id of
                                                                                                    // Screen tile
        String ScreentitleActualText = ScreenTitleFindElement.getText();// Get the Text of Title
        Assert.assertEquals("Tools & Settings", ScreentitleActualText);// compare Actual Result with Expected Result
    }

    @Test(priority = 3) // Verify that on Tools screen Your refferal code button is displayed & enabled
    public void VerifyThatYourRefferalButtonIsAvailableOnToolsScreen() {
        WebElement YourRefferalButtonGetElementById = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/imageView"));
        boolean YourRefferalButtonisDisplayed = YourRefferalButtonGetElementById.isDisplayed();
        boolean YourRefferalButtonisEnabled = YourRefferalButtonGetElementById.isEnabled();
        if (YourRefferalButtonisDisplayed == true && YourRefferalButtonisEnabled) {
            WebElement YourRefferalCodeTextId = driver
                    .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/tv_rate_this_location_text"));
            String YourRefferalCodeGetText = YourRefferalButtonGetElementById.getText();
            // System.out.print("Button Text" +YourRefferalCodeGetText );
            Assert.assertEquals("Your Referral Code", YourRefferalCodeGetText);// compare Actual Result with Expected
                                                                                // Result
        }
    }

    @Test(priority = 4)
    public void OpenYourReferralScreen() {
        WebElement YourRefferalButtonGetElementById = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/imageView"));
        boolean YourRefferalButtonisDisplayed = YourRefferalButtonGetElementById.isDisplayed();
        boolean YourRefferalButtonisEnabled = YourRefferalButtonGetElementById.isEnabled();
        if (YourRefferalButtonisDisplayed == true && YourRefferalButtonisEnabled) {
            YourRefferalButtonGetElementById.click();
            WebElement ReferralScreenTitleId = driver
                    .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/tv_screen_title"));
            String ReferralScreenTitleGetText = ReferralScreenTitleId.getText();
            Assert.assertEquals("Referral Code", ReferralScreenTitleGetText);// compare Actual Result with Expected
                                                                                // Result
        } else {
            System.out.print("Test Case Failed:'Your Referral Code' Button is not Found on the Tool screen");
        }

    }

    @Test(priority = 5) // verify that on referral screen Referral code is exist
    public void verifyThatRefferalCodeExistOnRefferalScreen() {
        WebElement YourReferralCodeId = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/tv_referral_code_text"));

        if (YourReferralCodeId != null) {
            System.out.print("Test Case Passed :" + YourReferralCodeId.getText());
            Assert.assertNotNull(YourReferralCodeId);
        } else {
            System.out.print("Test Case Failed :your referral Code Not Found On Referral Screen");
            Assert.assertNotNull(YourReferralCodeId);
        }

    }
}
```

chrripik class is working fine seprately but not executed in xml file

```
package com.macrosoft.CherryPick;

import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertTrue;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import java.util.List;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.lang.model.element.Element;

import org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertFalse;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;

public class CherryPik extends Configuration {
    public static String ActualResultSearch;
    public static String ActualResultRecentLocation;
    public static String ActualResultRecentLocationForHomeSelection;
    public String ActualLocationSendKey = "test";
    String GetTextSaveMyLocation;

    public CherryPik() {
    }

    // verify that when user clicks on location button then system shows recent
    // Location ByDefault
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void RecentLocation() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement FindLocationElementByID = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/footer_nav_locations_btn"));
        FindLocationElementByID.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        // verify that Recent Button is Displayed
        boolean RecentButtonPresence = driver.findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/recent_loc"))
                .isDisplayed();
        // verify that Recent button is enabled
        boolean RecentButtonEnabled = driver.findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/recent_loc"))
                .isEnabled();
        if (RecentButtonPresence == true && RecentButtonEnabled == true) {
            System.out
                    .print("Test Casepass:Recent Location is showing by default when user clicks on Location button\n");

        } else {
            System.out.print("Test Case Failed:Recent Location Screen Not Found");

        }

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        // driver.findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/search_locations")).click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.print("Exception is displayed" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void If(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // verify that user can select the Location and Brands Name are displayed on the
    // Map
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void SearchLocation() throws InterruptedException {
        // AndroidElement FindElementLocationButton= (AndroidElement)
        // driver.findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/footer_nav_locations_btn"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/search_locations")).click();
        // verify if the “ Search” Field is displayed and enabled
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        // verify that search field is displayed
        boolean SearchFieldIsDisplayed = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/save_curr_to_my_loc_parent"))
                .isDisplayed();
        // verify that search field is enabled
        boolean SearchFieldIsEnabled = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/save_curr_to_my_loc_parent")).isEnabled();
        boolean OkButtonPresenece = driver.findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/btn_here_now"))
                .isDisplayed();
        boolean OkButtonVisible = driver.findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/btn_here_now"))
                .isEnabled();
        if (SearchFieldIsDisplayed == true && SearchFieldIsEnabled == true && OkButtonPresenece == true
                && OkButtonVisible == true) {
            // verify that User can select the the location from the drop down
            WebElement LocationSearchFieldElement = driver
                    .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/save_curr_to_my_loc_parent"));
            LocationSearchFieldElement.sendKeys("Tes");
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            WebElement autoComplete = driver.findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/list_view"));
            try {
                (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5/* sec */)).until(ExpectedConditions
                        .presenceOfElementLocated((By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/list_view"))));

            } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
                // System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            List<WebElement> autoCompleteList = driver
                    .findElements(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/tv_item_name"));

            Thread.sleep(1500);
            // autoCompleteList.get(0).click();
            if (autoCompleteList.size() == 0) {

                System.out.println("AutoSearch list NOT found\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("autoSearch list Found with elements:" + autoCompleteList.size());
                // System.out.println("autoSearch list Found with elements:
                // "+autoCompleteList.));
            }
            for (WebElement ac : autoCompleteList) {
                if (ac.getText().contains("Tesla WV") || ac.getText().contains("Home")) {
                    ActualResultSearch = ac.getText();
                    ac.click();

                    break;

                }

            }
            Thread.sleep(500);
            boolean AfterSelectionofLocationMapIsdisplayed = driver
                    .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/footer_nav_map_btn")).isDisplayed();
            if (AfterSelectionofLocationMapIsdisplayed == true) {
                System.out.println("Test Case pass:Brands are successfully displayed on the map \n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Test Case Failed:Brands are not displayed on the map \n");
            }
            // LocationSearchFieldElement.sendKeys("\t");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            // SelectElement selector = new SelectElement();
            // selector.SelectByIndex(2);
        } else {

            System.out.println("Search Field Not Found On 'Search All Screen'\n");
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.print("Exception is displayed" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Test(priority = 3) // verify that search Location is Exist in the Recent Location
    // List
    public void SearchLocationIsExistInTheRecentLocationList() throws InterruptedException {
        // String ExpectedResult="Tesla WV";
        // String ActualResultRecentLocation;

        Thread.sleep(100);
        RecentLocation();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement autoComplete = driver.findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/main_content"));
        try {
            (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5/* sec */)).until(ExpectedConditions
                    .presenceOfElementLocated((By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/main_content"))));

        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
            // System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        List<WebElement> autoCompleteList = autoComplete
                .findElements(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/tv_item_name"));

        Thread.sleep(1500);
        // autoCompleteList.get(0).click();
        if (autoCompleteList.size() == 0) {

            System.out.println("Search list NOT found\n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Search list Found with elements:" + autoCompleteList.size());
            // System.out.println("autoSearch list Found with elements:
            // "+autoCompleteList.));
        }
        for (WebElement ac : autoCompleteList) {
            // System.out.println("List Element Text:+"+ac.getText());
            if (ac.getText().contains(ActualResultSearch)) {
                // System.out.println("List Element Text:+"+ac.getText());
                ActualResultRecentLocation = ac.getText();
                System.out.println("List Element Text:+" + ActualResultSearch);
                // System.out.println("data in acutual search :"+ActualResultSearch);
                ac.click();
                // Thread.sleep(1000);
                break;
            }

        }
        Assert.assertEquals(ActualResultRecentLocation, ActualResultSearch);
        boolean AfterSelectionofLocationMapIsdisplayed = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/footer_nav_map_btn")).isDisplayed();
        if (AfterSelectionofLocationMapIsdisplayed == true) {
            System.out.println("Test Case pass:Brands are successfully displayed on the map \n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Case Failed:Brands are not displayed on the map \n");
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.print("Exception is displayed" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is my xml file and when I run it , it executes only 3 test cases

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="10" name="CherriPik" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.macrosoft.CherryPick.CherryPik"></class>
      <class name="com.macrosoft.CherryPick.ToolsReferralCode"> </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Regression -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: my xml file is : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="10" name="CherriPik" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.macrosoft.CherryPick.CherryPik"></class>
      <class name="com.macrosoft.CherryPick.ToolsReferralCode"> </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Regression -->
 
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your setup.

This can be fixed by the following xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
    <test name="ToolsReferralCode">
        <classes>
            <class name="pack.thisone.ToolsReferralCode" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="CherriPik">
        <classes>
            <class name="pack.thisone.CherryPik" />

        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Regression -->
</suite>
```

Notice that each test class is part of a different `<Test>` tag. `suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5` will ensure that the test will run in parallel.

There is another critical problem in your code when configuring the testng.xml file. It is how you have defined the `Config` class. `Config` class contains the driver and it is initialized in the `@BeforeSuite` method. The `Config` class is then inherited by all your test cases. When you add the test cases to the xml file under a suite, the @BeforeSuite methods are called only once. So your first test will get the driver object initialized while the second test will get `null` when trying to call the `driver`. So replace the @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite with @BeforeTest and @AfterTest

```
public class Configuration {
    public String driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void cherryPikLaunch() {
        System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - cherryPikLaunch");
        driver = "driver";
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void close_browser() {
        System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - close_browser");
    }
}

public class CherryPik extends Configuration {
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void RecentLocation() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - RecentLocation - " + driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void SearchLocation() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() +" - SearchLocation - " + driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void SearchLocationIsExistInTheRecentLocationList() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - SearchLocationIsExistInTheRecentLocationList - " + driver);
    }
}

public class ToolsReferralCode extends Configuration {
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void OpenToolsScreen() {
        System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - OpenToolsScreen - " + driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void OnToolsScreenTitlePresist() {
        System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - OnToolsScreenTitlePresist - " + driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void VerifyThatYourRefferalButtonIsAvailableOnToolsScreen() {
        System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                + " - VerifyThatYourRefferalButtonIsAvailableOnToolsScreen - " + driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 4)
    public void OpenYourReferralScreen() {
        System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - OpenYourReferralScreen - " + driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 5)
    public void verifyThatRefferalCodeExistOnRefferalScreen() {
        System.out.println(
                "Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - verifyThatRefferalCodeExistOnRefferalScreen - " + driver);
    }
}
```

The above code structure would produce the follwoing output

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Thread12 - cherryPikLaunch
Thread13 - cherryPikLaunch
Thread12 - OpenToolsScreen - driver
Thread13 - RecentLocation - driver
Thread13 - SearchLocation - driver
Thread12 - OnToolsScreenTitlePresist - driver
Thread12 - VerifyThatYourRefferalButtonIsAvailableOnToolsScreen - driver
Thread13 - SearchLocationIsExistInTheRecentLocationList - driver
Thread12 - OpenYourReferralScreen - driver
Thread13 - close_browser
Thread12 - verifyThatRefferalCodeExistOnRefferalScreen - driver
Thread12 - close_browser
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.716 sec - in TestSuite
```

I have added the Thread number in the `System.out.println` to show that the two tests are running in parallel in 2 threads and to understand the order of execution.

Also I have printed the value of driver to show that the driver is initialized in the `@BeforeTest` class. See what happens when you change @BeforeTest to @BeforeSuite (Hint: you will see null).

Comment: thanks for your  the dedication and quick response, your answer is very helpful for me but I want to execute all test cases in the same thread means i want to launch the application one time and execute all test cases of CLASS A, and then Class B and then Class C and so on , can it is possible  through in XML?means i want to execute all classes in 1 thread instead of before execute we are launching the application every time i want to launch the application 1 time and execute all test cases in same thread ..thanks

Comment: added another answer

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to run the all tests in the same driver instance**

To run all the test cases by opening the browser exactly once, do the following.

1. Change the driver to static and the @BeforeTest and @AfterTest to @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite

   ```
   public class Configuration {
       public static String driver;

       @BeforeSuite
       public void cherryPikLaunch() {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - cherryPikLaunch");
           driver = "driver";
       }

       @AfterSuite
       public void close_browser() {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - close_browser");
           driver = null;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Access the driver object in the Test classes as static members `Configuration.driver`

   ```
   public class ToolsReferralCode {
       @Test(priority = 1)
       public void OpenToolsScreen() {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - OpenToolsScreen - " + Configuration.driver);
       }

       @Test(priority = 2)
       public void OnToolsScreenTitlePresist() {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - OnToolsScreenTitlePresist - " + Configuration.driver);
       }

       @Test(priority = 3)
       public void VerifyThatYourRefferalButtonIsAvailableOnToolsScreen() {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                   + " - VerifyThatYourRefferalButtonIsAvailableOnToolsScreen - " + Configuration.driver);
       }

       @Test(priority = 4)
       public void OpenYourReferralScreen() {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - OpenYourReferralScreen - " + Configuration.driver);
       }

       @Test(priority = 5)
       public void verifyThatRefferalCodeExistOnRefferalScreen() {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                   + " - verifyThatRefferalCodeExistOnRefferalScreen - " + Configuration.driver);
       }
   }

   public class CherryPik {
       @Test(priority = 1)
       public void RecentLocation() throws InterruptedException {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - RecentLocation - " + Configuration.driver);
       }

       @Test(priority = 2)
       public void SearchLocation() throws InterruptedException {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - SearchLocation - " + Configuration.driver);
       }

       @Test(priority = 3)
       public void SearchLocationIsExistInTheRecentLocationList() throws InterruptedException {
           System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                   + " - SearchLocationIsExistInTheRecentLocationList - " + Configuration.driver);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Include the `Configuration` class in the test as below

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
   <suite name="Suite" parallel="none" thread-count="5">
       <test name="ToolsReferralCode">
           <classes>
               <class name="pack.thisone.Configuration"/>
               <class name="pack.thisone.ToolsReferralCode" />
           </classes>
       </test>
       <test name="CherriPik">
           <classes>
               <class name="pack.thisone.CherryPik" />

           </classes>
       </test> <!-- Regression -->
   </suite>
   ```
4. Set `parallel="none"` in the `suite tag`

Output will be as below

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Thread1 - cherryPikLaunch
Thread1 - OpenToolsScreen - driver
Thread1 - OnToolsScreenTitlePresist - driver
Thread1 - VerifyThatYourRefferalButtonIsAvailableOnToolsScreen - driver
Thread1 - OpenYourReferralScreen - driver
Thread1 - verifyThatRefferalCodeExistOnRefferalScreen - driver
Thread1 - RecentLocation - driver
Thread1 - SearchLocation - driver
Thread1 - SearchLocationIsExistInTheRecentLocationList - driver
Thread1 - close_browser
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.201 sec - in TestSuite
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable feedbacks but when calls the static members in the test calls and execute the XML file then system with a java null pointer exception ..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite" parallel="none" thread-count="5">
  <test  name="CherriPik" >
    <classes>
    <class name="com.macrosoft.CherryPick.Configuration"></class>
      <class name="com.macrosoft.CherryPick.SetMapDistance"></class>
      
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Regression -->
  <test name="test" >
    <classes>
       <class name="com.macrosoft.CherryPick.UnHideBrand"> </class> 
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Regression -->
</suite> <!-- suite -->

Comment: public  AndroidDriver driver=driver=Configuration.driver;    when i access the static members in the test class  then system through an exception , how i can access the static members in test class ?

Comment: I am assuming that `public AndroidDriver driver=Configuration.driver;` is added to all your test class as a instance variable (outside the @Test methods). The issue is that when this assignment is made, @BeforeSuite method is not invoked. So your driver is null. TestNG invokes all the classes before hand. Use Configuration.driver every where you used driver before. Eg: `Configuration.driver.findElements()`

Comment: thanks for your feedback but i want to done work with the driver.findElement instead of configuration.driver because i have written down 3500 lines of code so this is very difficult for me to change the overall structure of the project can it is possible can i work with driver.find element ?

Comment: Try extending the configuration class in all tests. I have not tested it. It's worth a try